# How to convert selected text to sentence case?

Tags: windows-xp, autohotkey

How to convert selected text to sentence case?

like

How Are YOU

to this

How are you

Comment: @ChrisF - Word 2007 and notepad both

Answer (score 2):

```
^!v::  
clipboard:=ClipboardAll  
StringLower, string, clipboard  
StringTrimLeft, output, string, 1  
StringLeft, FirstChar, string, 1  
StringUpper, FirstChar, FirstChar  
sendraw %FirstChar%%output%  
Return
```

Horribly hacky, but it works :)

Proof: How are you

Comment: lol @ the String trim. XD. Creative.

Comment: I write my worst code before caffeine, but it always works! I bet somebody's gonna come and tell me there's a function for it anyway :P

Comment: it's not working it's giving this output 
^!v::  

clipboard:=clipboardall  

stringlower, string, clipboard  

stringtrimleft, output, string, 1  

stringleft, firstchar, string, 1  

stringupper, firstchar, firstchar  

sendraw %firstchar%%output%  

return:

Comment: @Jitendra; That's correct output. Unfortunately I didn't have time to support multiple lines. (It's capitalising the ^ in ^!v, thus you see no capitalisation)

Comment: I want to change "How Are YOU" to "How are you" and this script is not working.

Comment: @Jitendra It is working absolutely fine over here, if you have issues with it it is almost certainly due to settings changes you have made within the script. Try it in a totally blank script.

Comment: just paste a source of whole file in ur answer

Comment: That *is* the whole of the source file. What happens when you trigger it? Is it outputting anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

In word 2003, select the text, "format" menu, "change case", "sentence case"